# How do you turn off the Action Log Data Collector in Microsoft Test Manager 2010?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

Microsoft Test Manager 2010 does not support Silverlight applications, so when I navigate from a test to my Silverlight 4 app running in IE, I get a popup notifying me that there is a compatibility issue.  This is really annoying.  Doing some Googling, I found out that the solution is to disable the Action Log Data Collector.  I cannot locate this setting in Test Manager 2010.  Does anyone know where it is ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Testing Center click on Plan (it shows the current test plan). Click on Properties. In "Run Settings" / "Manual runs" section choose 'Local Test Run' for "Test Settings". Then click Open link next to this drop down. In the opened window select Data and Diagnostics and uncheck all items under Role Local.